# Environment that eats up (ignores) text inside it

Tags: macros, environments, comments

I want to replicate the environment `comment` from the `comment` package:

```
\begin{comment}
Hidden stuff.
\end{comment}
```

which prints just nothing, instead of using `%` to comment things out.

I can do it with a command, such as `\def\comment#1{}`, and now I want to turn it into an environment.

The motivation is to make an environment that would conditionally hide the text completely or do something with it, such as change color:

```
\@ifundefined{flag}%
{\newenvironment{flagged}{\it\color{red}(}{)}}%
{\newenvironment{flagged}{\comment\bgroup}{\egroup}}
```

In the second case the intention is to make the text argument of the macro: `\comment\bgroup Hidden stuff\egroup`. This does not work because `\bgroup\egroup` cannot delimit an argument of a macro.

```
\includepackage{comment}
...
{\newenvironment{flagged}{\begin{comment}}{\end{comment}}}
```

does not work either, I guess because the `comment` package expects a literal string `\end{comment}`:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `comment` package provides a mechanism to do this via `\specialcomment` and `\excludecomment`.